# I got an error like this to create a project(Vue.js) using the GUI

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

Starting GUI...

Ready on http://localhost:8000

node:events:368

```
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^
```

Error: spawn cmd ENOENT

```
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
```

(node:internal/child_process:282:19)
at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:475:16)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)

Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit

(node:internal/child_process:288:12)
at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:475:16)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {

errno: -4058,

code: 'ENOENT',

syscall: 'spawn cmd',

path: 'cmd',

spawnargs: [ '/c', 'start', '""', '/b', 'http://localhost:8000' ]
}

Node.js v17.2.0

Comment: please add some code so that we understand better

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.